# How can I create a multi-value dictionary?

Tags: python, sql-server, project

I have user info from a SQL Server - a username and password -
and now I want to create a dictionary

```
{ID : password}
```

but if I have more then one it just saves the last one I put in

```
for i in (cursor.execute('select * from Person')):
    idNameDict = {i[0]:i[3]}
```

I want to do it this way so it would be easier for me to do check if the based on the ID that the password input would be correct because right now and it seems to long

```
def logIn(userName,userPassword):
    userID=[]
    global p
    lbl = Label(root)
    lbl.grid(row=5,column=1)
    for user in (cursor.execute('select * from Person')):
        p = Person(user[0],user[1],user[2],user[3])
        userID.append(p)
    for id in userID:
        if userName == id.ID:
            if userPassword == id.password:
                userPage(root,userName)
            else:
                lbl.config(text= "Invalid Password")
        else:
            lbl.config(text= "Invalid User Name")
```

Comment: Why would you fetch the whole table every time?  Just do `cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE ID=?", (id,))`.  Then there's no looping required, and you reduce the network traffic.

Comment: And I sincerely hope you aren't planning to store passwords in plain text in any production system.

Comment: no just for now, I'm just building a pet project. So it wont be for mass market or anything just for myself

Comment: Im just not sure, if best practice is to just pull all the info from SQL and then just place it in a class and work off of that or just pull data from SQL

Comment: Each call only needs one username.  This code, specifically, is not caching anything.  It's reading the entire table for every call.  Much better just to read the one name you need.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code doesn't work properly because you declare the dictionary from scratch in each iteration. You need to do it in the following way:

```
idNameDict = {}
for i in (cursor.execute('select * from Person')):
    idNameDict[i[0]] = i[3]
```

Comment: Yeah I know it was just declaring from scratch. Can you explain why this works?

Comment: If you declare the dictionary from scratch, then all previous data is lost and only the last item will be kept.
In my code, The dictionary is declared only at the beginning and then all items are added in the loop and kept in the dictionary